# How can I view the pushd stack in the Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, ms-dos

As per the title, how can I view the `pushd` stack in the Windows command line?

I see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1641191/where-does-bash-store-the-directory-stack-used-in-pushd-popd-dirs) for Linux doesn't have an answer, so I'm not holding my breath for a Windows command line answer.  As that Linux user noted, the OS knows *somewhere* what's in the `pushd` stack so `popd` can get back there, but is it accessible at the command line?

Comment: pushd and popd are like cd.  They are built into cmd.exe and powershell.  As to where the stack lives is anyone's guess.

Comment: That makes sense, @cup.  Thanks.